# Decent Video Chat API?

Tags: api, video, video-streaming, lamp

Just wondering. I'm looking to build a small web application with a single page. It will essentially be a video chat page so I'm looking for an API I can use or any other solutions?

This would be run on a LAMP stack.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A SO search reveals [lots of similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=web%20video%20chat%20api) which are worth checking/contributing to.

It depends if you want something free or are prepared to pay but some things that come up are (mind I havent used any of these myself):

- http://www.tokbox.com/
- http://code.google.com/apis/talk/open_communications.html#developer
- http://www.process-one.net/en/blogs/article/oneteam_media_server_by_processone
- https://sites.google.com/site/webrtc/ (Now at: https://webrtc.org/ )
- https://www.skype.com/en/developer/
- http://farsight.freedesktop.org/wiki/
- https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video
- Some MS libraries are mentioned here: [Developing a Video Chat Application with high quality video streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470698/developing-a-video-chat-application-with-high-quality-video-streaming)
- Apple had promised to open up [FaceTime](http://www.apple.com/uk/ios/ios5/?cid=mc-uk-g-fae-facetime) but so far nothing has happened

To get up and running quickly it seems tokbox would be most suitable.

Comment: http://www.securevideo.com has released an API, based on the VSee platform

Comment: SightCall (I work at SightCall) also provides APIs and SDKs to add video chat to a website or a mobile app. This service run on top of Weemo’s cloud infrastructure so you don’t have to set up your own. –

Answer (score 5):

Look into WebRTC, it's a new technology by Google and doesn't require any plugins! It's still under development but the code is available and working at the moment!

Comment: I can see that this was your first answer to a question, so you didn't have the rep to post this as a comment, but in the future, you might want to consider posting this as a comment. Answers are supposed to be a solution to the problem that you are pretty confident will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit of advert, but you could try to look into http://www.addlive.com. We offer comprehensive set of APIs allowing you to build RTC apps on the web (JS bindings on top of a plug-in and native WebRTC if available) and native mobile and dekstop SDKs.

Comment: AddLive has been acquired by Snapchat and isn't adding any new customers.

Answer (score 0):

[Vidyo.io](https://vidyo.io) can help with this. (Full disclosure: I work for Vidyo.) It provides a simple JavaScript API that supports WebRTC capable browsers and a plug-in for Safari and IE. We also have sample apps on our github page https://github.com/vidyo to help you create a page simile to what you're looking for.