# Implementation of video call in Xamarin forms, what options do I have?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am looking to create a videocall app but I am a bit unsure where I should start. Preferably I would like to implement a service like skype or something similiar to avoid creating the entire code myself but maybe that is what i have to do. I have a camera stream already implemented (avfoundation) but i can imagine there is a lot of work left in order to create a fully working videocall code.

What options do you guys think I have? Is it possible to implement skype for xamarin forms? I also saw a component called Twilio that you can use in xamarin forms but it seems like it is not supporting a video call, atleast not the component in xamarin forms.

Any help, tips, links is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you may want to look at this: [Videocalling in desktop application .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880108/video-calling-in-desktop-application-net)

Comment: will check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Azure Media Services for this.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/

Comment: Sounds interesting! Are there any guides on how to implement this to a xamarin.forms app?

Comment: @UnoDosCode I think this is a great way to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-get-started